# Why do all ASP.NET MVC websites allow and ignore the string "/(F())/" in front of ANY URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I noticed that requests to my ASP.NET web app succeed even if I prefix the URL with `/(F())/` which is nonsense. The usual action method is hit. `Request.Url` does *not* show the URL prefix. So if I request `/(F())/x` the action sees `Request.Url == "/x"`

I then tried other ASP.NET MVC sites such as Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/(F())/questions/43593952/why-do-all-asp-net-mvc-websites-allow-and-ignore-the-string-f-in-front-o

According to Fiddler the request is being made as intended:

[image]

As you can see the request URL is correct and the server replies without redirect with the full content. The browser window shows that URL as well.

This URL *does* work. So I conclude that *something* in the framework causes this request to be rewritten and the prefix dropped. It looks like the Stack Overflow application was unaware of the prefix.

The same result occurs in a fresh MVC app created in Visual Studio 2017 on .NET 4.6.2 on Windows 7.

Another funny victim: https://www.microsoft.com/(F(blah))/en-us/default.aspx (The Microsoft homepage).

The string `(F())` is not special. See the comments for other strings that work e.g. `/(F(pV0))`.

Since my ASP.NET code is blind to the original URL (`Request.Url` does not contain the prefix) I seemingly cannot even detect this condition and fail the request.

I have not confirmed that this is an MVC problem. It seems hard to find the culprit in the huge sea of functionality that ASP.NET+IIS ship with. Who knows what features are turned on by default?! I don't think anyone really knows :)

At the very least this is an SEO problem but I find it disturbing as well to not know what's going on. That's why I'm investigating. **What behavior is that and how to get rid of it?**

Comment: Does it also work with static files? And how on earth did you spot this one?! :) EDIT: It does work with static files... hmmmmm

Comment: My app generated a random prefix during URL generation because of a bug. *That* bug I have not caught yet but I found astonished that the bad URL works. I even resorted to remote debugging my production server and pausing the live traffic with the debugger.

Comment: Just testing on this very page, it looks like it's only happening for me with a single capital letter.  Lowercase, multiple letters, and numbers all result in the expected error response.  (Though it looks like I can put a lot more in that inner set of parentheses...)

Comment: @David no, it works with long random strings. Upper, lower, numbers. Not sure which ones exactly work, but this one does: `/(F(pV0))`.

Comment: @usr: That's what I mean, anything reasonable (not horribly URL-malformed) that I try within those inner parentheses is working.  But the `F` itself, at least for me, needs to be a single capital letter.  Any letter seems to be working for me.

Comment: @DavidG Can you confirm if those static files requests are still going through the ASP.NET pipeline? What happens if IIS is configured to go directly to the native static file handler without the ASP.NET pipeline?

Comment: @Dai Yeah, static content still works with this weird URL structure

Comment: I am wondering if it's something to do with the way IIS works with session IDs, from memory you can turn on cookieless sessions where the ID is passed over the URL.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the cookieless URLs. If you add `<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="UseUri" />` into `system.web` you will get a URL that looks very similar to what you have.

Comment: @DavidG omg now I understand the bug. I am caching `UrlHelper.Url` generated URLs. When someone comes to the site in cookieless mode he will insert this garbage into the cache. That's the bug I'm actually after. How nasty.

Comment: Oh dear haha. Well, I'm not sure how you disallow these URLs, perhaps you could remove the `SessionStateModule`? But I'm guessing you need it for this app.

Comment: I hope it's .NET code that I can decompile and find the most complete remedy. The Stack Overflow guys will have to solve this issue for SEO. Maybe they can post their solution.

Comment: May be worth trying in Kestrel to see if the same behaviour is there? Not sure if that supports cookieless out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by the [ASP.NET cookieless feature set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx). The URL may now look like this:

http://example.com/MyWebApplication/(A(XXXX)S(XXXX)F(XXXX))/home.aspx

Breaking it down:

- A(XXXX): This is the Anonymous-ID. It is used to identify the (anonymous) user accessing your application. The string may or may-not be encrypted, depending on your configuration settings in the  section.
- S(XXXX): This is the Session-ID (same as V1.1).
- F(XXXX): This is the Forms Authentication ticket.

Since cookieless mode is entirely obsolete, causes SEO problems and confusion I **recommend to disable all possible cookieless features on all ASP.NET websites immediately.**

> For each of the above features (Forms Authentication, Anonymous Identification, and Session State), you can control if and when the cookiesless feature will be used, and when the cookieless feature will be used instead. The configuration setting controlling this is:
>   cookieless="UseCookies | UseUri | UseDeviceProfile | AutoDetect"

In my case I set:

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="false" />
<sessionState ... cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

You will need to adapt this to your needs.

This hopefully addresses the *generation* of these URLs but seemingly it does not prevent the framework from (silently) accepting such a URL. [The documentation claims that a header `AspFilterSessionId` will be present](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but I found that not to be the case.

**For now I have no solution for blocking *requests* to these unwanted URLs.**